# PhoneGap application display only White Screen in android device

Tags: android, cordova, apk, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm a beginner PhoneGap application development. I create PhoneGap application but showing only white screen in andorid device. Application is working on web is porperly but in android device showing only white screen.

Here below screen shot of android device after compile the apk file of phone gap application.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiZpI.png

Answer (score 1):

> Application is working on web is porperly but in android device showing only white screen.

Try setting `<base href="www">` in your `index.html`. Either way you should install cordova's browser platform for local testing:

```
cordova platform add browser
```

and test your app in the browser using

```
cordova run browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Was your code optimized  I mean did  u use bootstrap or something,if not your code can't distinguish between mobile and desktop screens(causing overflow)